# Firebase notifications working but not opening app on android with Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase notifications on my app and for some reason, the notifications will not open the app on android. I really don't have any clue what is causing this because some apps work fine and others don't.

Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this?

I use this code to send notifications to a specific device. Sometimes they open, other times they dont.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var Geopoint = require("geopoint");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceaccount.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com"
});
var db = admin.database();

const title = "My Test";
const body = "My Test Body";
const deepLink = "http://google.com/";
const token = "firebaseDeviceToken";

var payload = {
  notification: {
    title,
    body,
    sound: "default",
    deepLink
  },
  data: {
    title,
    body,
    deepLink
  }
};

var options = {
  priority: "high",
  timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
  contentAvailable: true
};

console.log(payload);

return admin
  .messaging()
  .sendToDevice(token, payload, options)
  .then(r => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ r }));
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ r: err }));
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Can we see some code? It's _impossible_ to detect what's wrong with your app without seeing your code...

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS See updated question.